# Confusion with the reconstruction conjecture?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

After reading about the reconstruction conjecture for graphs, I came up with what I thought was a proof by contradiction. Consider the class $T$ of (isomorphism classes of) finite graphs, and the function $D$ such that $D(A)$ is the deck of $A$. The Reconstruction conjecture states $D(G)=D(H) \iff G=H$. Assume this is true. Then $D(D(G))=D(D(H)) \iff G=H$. Continuing gives that the null graph is equal to the null graph $\iff G=H$.

Comment: $D(G)$ is a set of graphs, not a graph itself, and the reconstruction conjecture requires a minimum number of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in graph theory, but I don't see what the type of $D(D(G))$ is. I think the problem comes from defining $D$ on decks of graphs, rather than just graphs. Also, the conjecture isn't true for graphs with two vertices anyway, so the induction should stop before that.

Comment: We could define D intuitively by

Comment: f(X)={f(x)| x is an element of X} is a commonly known notation. However here we would want the MULTI set . Also a (multi) set of graphs is interpretable as a graph with each element being a component.

Comment: Then you have to strengthen your inductive assumption by quite a bit, and I'm not sure what they would look like. Also, what do you mean "interpretable". How would you do that in a consistent and useful way here?

Comment: an interpretation could be a representation (graph figure) in 3-space.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is nice, but the reconstruction conjecture excludes some very small graphs. Both graphs on 2 vertices have the same deck.